# C++ test for run time type information

Tags: c++

Is it possible to just check for RTTI without having the overhead of catching an exception?  dynamic_cast just throws an exception and I just need to see if something has RTTI or not in a highly used section of code where an exception would be a huge problem...

Comment: `dynamic_cast` to a pointer type does not throw an exception. But I am still unsure what you are trying to do. What do you mean by "Has RTTI"? An illustrative piece of example code would be nice.

Comment: [`typeid`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid)

Comment: Well it does throw an exception on a pointer to say a char*... Basically I just want to test if something is a char* or a real class type with RTTI for a string formatting function.  Unfortunately the type is being passed in to a function so typeid won't work...

Comment: The code in question is a template?

Comment: No it's a variable length argument function so the type isn't known.  I guess it's not really possible to do this efficiently.

Comment: Thanks anyway guys, sorry for the confusion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the pointer you create with dynamic_cast against NULL. If it equals NULL, the cast did not work. If it doesn't, the cast worked, and there will be no exceptions thrown.